# Does ref has a double meaning in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, ref, vue-reactivity

I can use ref to make a value 'reactive'
[Official Doc](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref)

```
const count =ref(0)
```

I also can use it to put a reference to a DOM Element.
[Official Doc](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-special-attributes.html#ref)

```
<button ref=mybutton> OK </button>
```

I think I understood the use cases of both.

What bothers me is that is  seems like 2 different usages  and It would be poor implementation to name 2 different things with the same name ?

I can feel I'm missing something,  like its probably the same mechanism that operates underneath, but I don't really understand or find documentation to get that 'Ohhh' moment.

Can someone points me to some articles, explanation ?

I read the official DOC, googled it even ask chatGPT but I only get back to basic usages of ref I know how to use it, I want to know how it works.

Comment: The second one is template ref, that's the term. In composition api, refs are used for template refs, that's what the docs show

Comment: Both use  import { ref } from 'vue'  though. 
There must be some kind of logic of using the same 'symbol' to do different things.

Comment: A ref from composition api is just reactive object with `value` property, it can be used for many things, including template refs. In V3, `ref="mybutton"`  is similar to `:ref="(el) => mybutton = el"`, in case this explanation is clearer. It should have been `:ref="(el) => mybutton.value = el"`, but `.value` part is always skipped inside templates